# No matter what, won't read through text and then write C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to finish my college assignments but I can't figure out what is wrong with the coding. I am suppose to take the text file, read through it and output with headings, a total weight, total height with a model counter, all while it sorts and writes out the models whom meet the assignment criteria. It should resemble this:

Name     Gender     Weight     Height     Eye Color     Hair Color

Jane Doe F 135 5'8 Blue Blonde

Total Weight: 135lbs

Total Height: 5'8

Models: 1

Here's what I wrote so far, but it won't even write the heading. I have also written it many ways, I have even taken the professor's code and tweaked it. I am coding on MacOS, with VisualStudio.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ModelRoster
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"/Users/jennie/Desktop/Computer Programming/Assignment 4/Models.txt");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"/Users/jennie/Desktop/Computer Programming/Assignment 4/Payroll.txt");
            string line;

            //input
            string Name;
            int Weight;
            int Height;
            char Eyes = new char();
            char Hair = new char();
            char Gender = new char();

            int TotalW = 0;
            int TotalH = 0;
            int Mdls = 0;

            //misc
            int MWidth = 5;
            int MLength = 0;
            string Title;
            int End = 0;

            //heading
            Title = ("Name\t\tGender\t\tWeight\t\tHeight\t\tEye Color\t\tHair Color");
            MLength = Title.Length;
            End = (MWidth - MLength) / 2 + MLength;
            sw.WriteLine(Title.PadLeft(End));
            //
            sw.WriteLine(" ");

            //output
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please check your code formatting, make sure to highlight the code and press the `{ }` in the toolbar to format it correctly.

Comment: you don't close the stream

Comment: Any particular reason you're using streams and not the methods provided by `System.IO.File`?

Comment: wrap your stream's in `using` blocks to ensure they are closed when you are done with them.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your stream's in using blocks to ensure they are closed when you are done with them. This will also ensure that any open stream writer is flushed when it is closed.

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"/Users/jennie/Desktop/Computer Programming/Assignment 4/Models.txt"))
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"/Users/jennie/Desktop/Computer Programming/Assignment 4/Payroll.txt"))
{
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with using like Igor comentes, or read all the text into a Variable, then with another using write all into the file.

Is always recommended to use the using foro ensure the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tiny nudge in the right direction for you:

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\CYA\TestDuece.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Name\t\tGender\t\tWeight\t\tHeight\t\tEye Color\t\tHair Color");
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\CYA\Test.txt"))
        {
            string stringy;
            while ((stringy = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(stringy);
            }  
        }
    }
```